# Conditional Distribution of Statistic from Poisson Distribution is Binomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. from a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$, so that the common pdf is given by:

$$f_{X_i}(x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$$

Define the statistic $S=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.  Clearly $S\sim POISSON(n\lambda)$

Prove that the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $S=s$ is binomial with parameters $s,n^{-1}$.  That is, prove:

$$X_1|_{S=s}\sim B(s,n^{-1})$$

This is really tripping me up since $S$ is actually composed of $X_1$.  I have no idea what the joint distribution would be, so I can't take that approach to find the conditional.  So I'm really unsure of how to prove this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
Pr(X_1 = k | \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=s) &= \frac{Pr(X_1=k)Pr(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=s|X_1=k)}{Pr(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=s)} \\
&= \frac{Pr(X_1=k)Pr(\sum_{i=2}^n X_i=s-k)}{Pr(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=s)} \\
\end{align}

Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You have a stream of point events generated by $n$ independent Poison processes occuring at identical rates.   What is the probability that *any* particular point event was generated from process 1?   Is that dependent on knowing if *any other* point event was so generated?   Why so?

Then can it now be argued that the count of point events generated by prossess 1 among $s$ such events is a count of 'successes' among a stream of $s$ independent Bernouli trials with identical 'success' rate?

---

Alternatively, use the definition of conditional probability, and the nature of a sum of independent poisson events , to identify that $$\mathsf P(X_1=k\mid S_n=s)~{=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X_1=k)\mathsf P(S_{n-1}=s-k)}{\mathsf P(S_n=s)}\\=\dfrac{\lambda^k\mathsf e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\dfrac{((n-1)\lambda)^{s-k}\mathsf e^{-(n-1)\lambda}}{(s-k)!}\dfrac{s!}{(n\lambda)^s\mathsf e^{-n\lambda}}}$$